# Not able to access office resources - need to install openswan xl2tpd and l2tp-ipsec-vpn in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, 18.04

I am not able to access office resources. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell laptop. L2tp/Ipsec Vpn has been installed in my laptop but not able to access resources.

We have set up L2tp/Ipsec in Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked fine with the below steps

Packages required:

```
sudo apt-get install openswan xl2tpd l2tp-ipsec-vpn
```

In the file `/etc/ppp/Lybrate.options.xl2tpd`

How can we install these package in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: what do you mean by "office resources". Please be more specific

Comment: Assuming you have been given some information from the "office" about how to login (i.e. a gateway and user credentials) and your office usually works with Windows, then what step is unclear to you?

Comment: We have setup L2tp/Ipsec in ubuntu 14.04, Its work fine for us. See the below steps- 1. Packages required:
$ sudo apt-get install openswan
$ sudo apt-get install xl2tpd
$ sudo apt-get install l2tp-ipsec-vpn
In the file /etc/ppp/Lybrate.options.xl2tpd

 How can we install these package in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What exactly did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Close voters: Answer crafted.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the answer you want, but as of this moment there are no versions of [the openswan package available beyond 14.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openswan&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [no source package for bionic](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/openswan) either. The same is true for the [l2tp-ipsec-vpn package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=l2tp-ipsec-vpn&searchon=names) which also doesn't have a [current source package for bionic](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/l2tp-ipsec-vpn) at this moment.

For the above packages you could attempt to compile them from the latest sources available or test the [debian packages.](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) Either or neither of which may be successful in your environment.

The [xl2tpd package is available for bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xl2tpd+&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) in the [universe repository.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Since you require these resources an alternative would be to stick with 14.04 until such time as the required/desired packages are available (hopefully before April of 2019 when Trusty support expires).